# How to deleted elements of a list who are meeting a certain condition on React js

Tags: reactjs, onclick, use-state

I would like to delete all completed items from the to-do list when pressing a button.
How could I do that? My `useState` is like this :

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([
    { id: 58477, text: "Wash dishes", done: false },
    { id: 64851, text: "Bake a cake", done: true },
    { id: 59858, text: "Make a website", done: true },
])
```

And my code is like that:

```
export default function TodoListItem(){
    const [ todos, setTodos ] = useTodosContext()


    function deleteTodo(todo) {
        console.log("Clear completed")
    }

    return(
        <div>
            {todos.map(todo => <li><input type="checkbox" className="roundCheckBox"/>{todo.text}</li>)}
            <button onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo)}>CLEAR COMPLETED</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a higher order array method (like [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) / [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach))  on the todos-state array to segregate the done todos and then remove it from the state , updating state automatically makes react render the todoItems again this time with the new state i.e. without the completed items as you wanted

```js
let todos = [
{
  done: true,
  name: "i need to be removed"
},
{
  done: true,
  name: "useless"
}, 
{
  done: false,
  name: "i need to be kept"
},
{
  done: false,
  name: "useful"
}];
let elements_to_delete = todos.filter(todo => todo.done);
let elements_to_keep = todos.filter(todo => !todo.done);
console.log("\n Items to keep are :-");
console.log(elements_to_keep);
console.log("\n Items to delete are :-");
console.log(elements_to_delete);
```

The above snippet shows how you can filter out done item then all you need to do is use `setTodos(elements_to_keep)`in the deleteTodo function because elements_to_keep is also an array that can replace the previous array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
// replace your function deleteTodo with this:
const deleteTodo = useCallback((d_todo) => {
  setTodos(todos => todos.filter(todo => d_todo.id !== todo.id))
}, [])
```

This filters-out the todo being deleted.